# HibernateItemWriter in spring batch program tries to run without beginning transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

I have a spring batch program that successfully starts jobs that attempt to write data to a SQL database using a HibernateItemWriter. However, the hibernate code fails because a transaction never gets started:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: contains is not valid without active transaction
```

I configured a HibernateTransactionManager which I thought was supposed to take care of this but the problem persists. Maybe my spring batch configurations are still off? Here is the relevant code from the configuration file:

BatchConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BatchConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(Student.class);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getProperties());
        try {
            sessionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        final HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Student> studentItemWriter() {
        HibernateItemWriter<Student> writer = new HibernateItemWriter<Student>();
        writer.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
        return writer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I configured a HibernateTransactionManager which I thought was supposed to take care of this but the problem persists. Maybe my spring batch configurations are still off?

Declaring the `HibernateTransactionManager` as a bean in the application context in not enough, it will not be used by Spring Batch. You need to extend `DefaultBatchConfigurer` and override `getTransactionManager`. In your case, it should be something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

   @Override
   public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
      HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
      transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
      return transactionManager;
   }

}
```

Please refer to the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig) for more details about how to customize infrastructure beans required by Spring Batch.